# Date picker show wrong date when manual input

Tags: android, datepicker

When i manual input using date picker dialog, it return wrong date after set intital default. After date is pick, intital date is set to date is picked before. But it is wrong on only case:

Step 1: manual input day = 1 , month = 9 , year = 2018.

Step 2: show date picker, it show 1/9/2018, it is ok.

Step 3: selet last day of month. (30/9/2018). It will return 31/8/2018.

Note: it only happend when manual input and set first and last of month. 
I has use `datePicker.clearFocus();` but it seems does not work too!

```
date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                                          int dayOfMonth) {
                        // Do something with year, monthOfYear and dayOfMonth
                        mdate = dayOfMonth;
                        mmonth = monthOfYear;
                        myear = year;
                    }
                };

                mDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(MyAndroidAppActivity.this, date, myear, mmonth, mdate);
                mDatePickerDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Set", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        datePicker = mDatePickerDialog.getDatePicker();
                        // The following clear focus did the trick of saving the date while the date is put manually by the edit text.
                        datePicker.clearFocus();

                        date.onDateSet(datePicker, datePicker.getYear(), datePicker.getMonth(), datePicker.getDayOfMonth());

                    }
                });


            }

        });
        mDatePickerDialog.show();
```

Comment: You enter month -1 like as enter 9 you  enter 9-1 check this link https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog

Comment: i understand it, but it return 7, i already convert it to Aug.

Comment: same as return month +1

Comment: and date is wrong too

Comment: add your code too

Comment: i have use this library https://github.com/borax12/MaterialDateRangePicker

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31825071/2906060
Here the code i implement for